# Styled Component won't infer props when 'as' is set in attributes

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

Consider a simple Styled Component that is based on a different Styled Component:

```
const Base = styled.div``;
const Input = styled(Base)``;
```

`Base` has some styles shared between all of my Styled Components (some utilities, etc.). I want the `Input` component to be an `input` unless a different component is specified with an `as` attribute:

```
const Input = styled(Base).attrs(({ as: 'input' }) => ({ as }))``;
```

This works flawlessly except for the TypeScript errors:

```
<Input disabled={true} />
```

In the example above TS will complain that a `div` doesn't have a `disabled` attribute. However, it is not a `div` element anymore since we've set the `as` prop to `input` by default. It is an `input`. This error goes away if I specify `as` explicitly though:

```
<Input as="input" disabled={true} />
```

I don't want to specify the `as` prop explicitly every time given it is already set in the `attrs` and the code is functional. Any workaround for TS in this case?

Comment: interesting problem. all i've got are some slightly hacking workarounds for it like grab this from styled comps: `import { StyledComponent } from "styled-components";` then define a type for an input like `type StyleInputProps = StyledComponent<"input", {}, {}, never>;` then just cast it as that `const Input = styled(Base).attrs<{}>((props) => ({...props, as: "input" }))`` as StyleInputProps;` - can't really think of anything better off the top of my head

Comment: Thanks @TomFinney, this solution almost does it. However, I am now facing TS issues extending the `Input` with custom properties: `const Input = styled(Base).attrs<{}>((props) => ({...props, as: "input" }))<SomeCustomPropTypesHereBlowThingsUp>`` as StyleInputProps;`. Will keep looking for a solution.

Comment: UPDATE: Actually I seem to have resolved the issues I just mentioned by putting proper values in `StyledComponent<"input", {}, {}, never>`. Thanks so much!

Comment: For anyone who comes across this, while Tom's solution worked like a charm, I ended up creating several versions of the `Base` component for inputs, forms, labels, etc. e.g. `const Base = styled.input`.